# TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am using `"puppeteer": "^1.16.0",`.

When trying to test my page I get the following error:

I am using the following code to check if a table has the correct data:

```
await page.evaluate(async () => {
        let arr = [];
        let grabFromRow = (row, child) => row
            .querySelector(`td:nth-child(${child})`)
            .innerText // ====> if a value is 'null', I get an error here!
            .trim();

        const rows = "#table > thead > tr"

        const t = document.querySelectorAll(rows)
        for (const r of t) {
            arr.push({
                date: grabFromRow(r, 1).trim(),    
                quarter: grabFromRow(r, 2).trim(),
                consensus_estimate: grabFromRow(r, 3).trim(), 
                reported_eps: grabFromRow(r, 4).trim(),
                gaap_eps: grabFromRow(r, 5).trim(),
                revenue_estimate: grabFromRow(r, 6).trim(),
                actual_revenue: grabFromRow(r, 7).trim(), 
            });
        }
        console.log(arr);

        return arr
    });
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: means you do not have have element.... so `.querySelector(`td:nth-child(${child})`)` is not finding one. So debug to see what the selector is.

Comment: @epascarello I understand the error basically the tag looks like that `<td>&nbsp;</td>`. However I still want to get a value as in my original table the correct value is also ""

Comment: So do not do it in one line. Reference the element and if it exists use it, else return nothing.

Comment: @epascarello Thx for your reply! I kindly ask you to create an example to accept that on the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you get the error because the element does not exist. If you are expecting it to exist, then you need to figure out what in your selector is wrong.

Your comment is making it appear that you expect it to not exist in certain cases. So then you need to break it up and make sure the element exists before you try to access it.

```
let grabFromRow = (row, child) => {
  const td = row
    .querySelector(`td:nth-child(${child})`)
  return td ? td.innerText.trim() : ''
}
```

or use a truthy check and set a default if you want it in one line

```
let grabFromRow = (row, child) =>
  (row.querySelector(`td:nth-child(${child})`) || {innerText : ''})
    .innerText // ====> if a value is 'null', I get an error here!
    .trim();
```